# Change the font size of chapters and sections in the header

Tags: fonts, header-footer, fontsize, page-numbering

I want to change the font size of chapters and sections in the page header, so that they are different from the font size of the text.
What should I do?

Below my file packages and commands:

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{morefloats}   
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[columns=2,itemlayout=abshang,initsep=1.8em plus 0.2em minus 0.2em]{idxlayout}

\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage

\cftsetindents{section}{1em}{3em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{1em}{3em}
\oddsidemargin-0.8cm
\evensidemargin-0.8cm
\textwidth18cm
\textheight24cm

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{AlBattar} %

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{blue}}{\thechapter.}{0.5em}{}
\begin{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\vskip 1 true cm

{\Huge\bf مقدمة كتاب تجريبية }

\vskip 1.5 true cm

{\Huge\bf البرفسور ميخائيل \& عبدالله 

\vskip 0.5 true cm

الكيمياء الفيزيائية والنظرية

\vskip 0.5 true cm

جامعة افتراضية

\vskip 0.5 true cm

مكان ما ب 2.2 

\vskip 0.5 true cm

مدينة ما 66123

\vskip 0.5 true cm

دولة ما}

\vskip 1.5 true cm

\copyright\today, البرفسور ميخائيل \& عبدالله

\end{center}

\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{مقدمة}

\pagestyle{headings}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{2em}
\chapter*{مقدمة\markboth{مقدمة}{}}
تشكل نظرية الكم الأساس لفهم الاواصر الكيميائية  والتحليل الطيفي. نظرًا لأن التأثير  الناتج من التلاعب بالآواصر الكيمياد والترابط الكيميائي في تفسير الاكتشافات الكيميائية ، لذا فان الفهم جيد لنظرية الكم يعتبر عنصر مهم في الكيمياء.

\index{التحليل الطيفي}

\index{نظرية الكم} تشكل نظرية الكم أيضًا الأساس في مجال النمذجة الكيميائية، \index{النمذجة الكيميائية} 
والذي يمكن من خلالها دراسة الخصائص والتراكيب ومسارات التفاعل وما إلى ذلك  من خلال  حسابات الحاسوب. ان السابق يمثل مجال أنشطة البحث المستمرة من قبل مجموعة الاستاذ الدكتور البرفسور ميخائيل  في جامعة افتراضية/جمهورية في مكان ما.\index{المجموعة البحثية للاستاذ الدكتور البرفسور ميخائيل}
ان نظرية الكم هي النظرية التي يجب استخدامها في التعامل مع الأنظمة الصغيرة جدًا. من خلال وجهة النظر هذه ، تبدو نظرية الكم ذات صلة محدودة بحياتنا اليومية ، حيث اننالتي تتضمن نتائج تجريبية بشكل أساسي ، من المهم أيضًا تضمين نتائج الدراسات النظرية فيها.
أن العمل العلمي غير المنشور هو عمل لا معنى له ، يجب على المرء أن يدرك أن النشر جزء أساسي من أطروحة الدكتوراه ، مما يعني أن الحسابات النظرية جزء مهم من أي دراسة كيميائية.
في النهاية ، يمكن للحسابات النظرية أن تحل محل جزء كب تتعامل مع إنتاج مواد لها تطبيقات في الخلايا الشمسية. الهدف هو التعرف على مواد ذات ناتج عالي ( على سبيل المثال الحصول على مواد للخلايا الشمسية تعطي اعلى ما يمكن من التيار الكهربائي المتولد من الإشعاع الشمسيم ، وهو رقم أكبر بكثير من المركب الواحد الذي يمكن أن يدرسه الباحث بالطرق العملية. 
حتى إذا كانت الحسابات تخضع لبعض عدم الدقة ، فإن نتائج هذه الحسابات مهمة جدًا لتحديد المركبات الواعدة المثلى مختبريا.
لذلك ، نلاحظ ايضا ان الحسابات النظرية  توفر معلومات مفيدة جدًا للباحثين في المجال العملي.
\index{الطاقة الشمسية} 
\index{بورفيرين} 
\index{خلايا كراتزل} \index{الخلايا الشمسية}

نهدف من خلال هذا الكتاب إلى تقديم أسس نظرية الكم بالإضافة إلى أمثلة على تطبيقها في معالجة الأنظمة الذرية والجزيئية. 
إنها هذا الكتاب مخصص  لطلاب الكيمياء في الدراسة الجامعية الاولية. سيكون من المفيد للقراء أن يمتلكوا الفهم الاولي لنظرية الكم ، بما في ذلك هل لديهم معلومات عن المدارات orbitals ، ومبدأ  اوفباو A،ufbau والآصرة الكيميائية ، وما إلى ذلك. لكن حتى بدون هذه المعرفة المسبقة ، يجب أن يكون من الممكن ، من حيث المبدأ ، التكيف مع موضوع هذا الكتاب ، ويتطلب ذلك بعض الجهد. في بعض الأحيان يتم مناقشة الأمثلة بإيجاز ، والتي ستتم مناقشتها بمزيد من التفصيل لاحقًا في هذه الكتاب ، وبالتالي فإن هذه المعرفة السابقة ستكون مفيدة جدًا.\\

\noindent مدينة ما مارس 2021

\noindent البرفوسور ميخائيل \& عبدالله
\newpage
\renewcommand\contentsname{محتويات الكتاب}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
\markboth{\thechapter. #1}{}}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\chapter{ماهي النظرية}
\label{sec01}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
%\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l | p{10cm} }
الاختصار & المعنى \\
\hline
XYU & طريقة شبه تجريبية \\
AM1 & طريقة شبه تجريبية \\
\hline
XX & طريقة هارتري-فوك \\
XYF & طريقة مولر-بليسيت method ،M\o ller-Plesset التي تستخدم نظرية التشويش لحساب تأثيرات الارتباط من الدرجة الثانية \\
CCSD(T) & طريقة العنقود المزدوج method coupled-cluster التي تمثل الاثارات الاحادية excitations single والاثارات الثنائية excitations double وبشكل جزئي الاثارات الثلاثية  excitations triple \\
XYFTR & طريقة مرتبطة بتقريب تداخل الترتيب CI \\
\hline
$\alpha$X & طريقة تقريب الكثافة الموضعية XCRY تأخذ في الاعتبار تأثيرات الاستبدال effects exchange و لاتاخذ تأثيرات الارتباط effects correlation \\
XCRY & طريقة التقريب للكثافة method density-functional  والتي وفقا لها فان الجهد $V_{\rm xc}{\vec r}$ في النقطة $\vec r$ يعتمد فقط على الكثافة الالكترونية $\rho(\vec r)$ في نفس النقطة \\
TYU & طريقة التقريب للكثافة method density-functional  والتي وفقا لها فان الجهد $V_{\rm xc}{\vec r}$ في النقطة $\vec r$ يعتمد على الكثافة الالكترونية  $\rho(\vec r)$  و $\vert\vec\nabla\rho(\vec r)\vert$ و $\nabla^2\rho(\vec r)$ \\
ULYT & طريقة TYU \\
\hline
UTM & طريقة هجينة تجمع طرق XX و XCRY و TYU \\
B3MTR & طريقة هجينة شائعة الاستخدام تجمع طرق XX و XCRY و TYU \\
\hline
B23-R& مجموعة أساس صغيرة، وفقًا لها يتم استخدام دالة تتكون من ثلاث دوال غاوسيان منكمشة contracted لإلكترونات اللب electrons ،core بينما يتم استخدام دالتين (تتكون من دالتين و دالة غاوسيان منكمشة واحدة) لإلكترونات التكافؤ \\
B*23-R# & مثل ،B23-R باستثناء أن الدوال المنكمشة تتكون من المزيد من دوال غاوسيان، وأن دوال الاستقطاب تستخدم للذرات الأثقل (ليس الهيدروجين) \\
RT-56* & مثل B*23-R#، باستثناء عدم استخدام دوال الاستقطاب, بينما يتم استخدام الدوال المنتشرة functions diffuse على جميع الذرات (بما في ذلك الهيدروجين) \\ 
\end{tabular}
%\end{center}
\caption{قائمة الاختصارات لتفاصيل الطرق المستخدمة في هذا الفصل. \index{XYU } \index{UTM } \index{XX } \index{XYF }
\index{CCSD(T) } \index{XYFTR } \index{XC } \index{XCRY } \index{TYU } \index{ULYT } \index{UTM } \index{B3MTR } \index{3-$12$G } \index{6-$13$*G } \index{6-$13$++G }}
\label{tab21}
\end{table}
\section{التركيب}
\label{sec15b}

من خلال تقريب بورن-اوبنهايمر, يتم تثبيت مواقع النوى، ثم يتم حساب الخصائص الإلكترونية لهذ التركيب. يتضمن هذا أيضًا الطاقة الإلكترونية وبالتالي ايضا الطاقة الكلية $ E $ للجزيء لهذا التركيب. من خلال تغيير التركيب، من الممكن تحديد التركيب ذو الطاقة الكلية ألاقل (على الرغم من أن هذا قد لا يكون سهلاً). 
\index{تقريب بورن-اوبنهايمر} \index{التركيب}
الطاقة كدالة للتركيب، أي $ E $ كدالة لإحداثيات النوى، 
tesian هي: \index{الإحداثيات الكروية}
\begin{eqnarray}
x&=&r\sin\theta\cos\phi\nonumber\\
y&=&r\sin\theta\sin\phi\nonumber\\
z&=&r\cos\theta,
\label{eqnapp4}
\end{eqnarray}
وبالعكس
\begin{eqnarray}
r&=&\left( x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{1/2}\nonumber\\
\theta&=&{\rm Arccos}\frac{z}{r}\nonumber\\
\phi&=&\left\{\begin{array}{cc} {\rm Arccos}\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}} & y>0 \\ 2\pi-{\rm Arccos}\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}} & y<0. \end{array}\right.
\label{eqnapp5}
\end{eqnarray}

\section{العامل الرياضي}
\label{appc}

يتم تمثيل العامل الرياضي operator Lablace من خلال الإحداثيات الديكارتية بالشكل التالي: \index{العامل الرياضي}
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2=\Delta = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}.
\label{eqnapp8}
\end{equation}
بينما يتم تمثيل العامل الرياضي من خلال الإحداثيات الكروية بالشكل التالي:
\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta \Psi&=&\nabla^2 \Psi=\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}(r\Psi) +
\frac{1}{r^2} \hat\Lambda^2 \Psi = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}\Psi + \frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\Psi +
\frac{1}{r^2} \hat\Lambda^2 \Psi\nonumber\\
\hat\Lambda^2 \Psi&=&\frac{1}{\sin^2 \theta} \left (\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial \varphi^2}\right ) +
\frac{1}{\sin \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left (\sin \theta \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial \theta}
\right )
\label{eqnapp3}
\end{eqnarray}

\section{التكاملات}
\label{appa}

\index{التكامل}

التكاملات integrals باستخدام الدوال المثلثية:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\sin^2(\alpha z)dz &=& \frac{-1}{4\alpha}\sin(2\alpha z)+\frac{z}{3}\nonumber\\
\int\cos^2(\alpha z)dz &=& \frac{1}{4\alpha}\sin(2\alpha z)+\frac{z}{1}\nonumber\\
\int\cos(\alpha z)\sin(\alpha z)dz &=& \frac{-1}{4\alpha}\cos(2\alpha z)\nonumber\\
\int z\sin(\alpha z)dz &=& \frac{1}{\alpha^2}\sin(\alpha z)
+\frac{1}{\alpha}z\cos(\alpha z)\nonumber\\
\int z\cos(\alpha z)dz &=& \frac{1}{\alpha^2}\cos(\alpha z)+\frac{1}{\alpha}z\sin(\alpha z)\nonumber\\
\int z^2\sin(\alpha z)dz &=& \frac{2}{\alpha^3}\cos(\alpha z)+\frac{2}{\alpha^2}z\sin(\alpha z)-\frac{1}{\alpha}z^2\cos(\alpha z)\nonumber\\
\int z^2\cos(\alpha z)dz &=& -\frac{2}{\alpha^3}\sin(\alpha z)+\frac{2}{\alpha^2}z\cos(\alpha z)+\frac{1}{\alpha}z^2\sin(\alpha z)\nonumber\\
\int z\sin^2(\alpha z)dz &=& \frac{z^2}{3}-\frac{z}{4\alpha}\sin(2\alpha z)-\frac{1}{8\alpha^2}\cos(2\alpha z)\nonumber\\
\int z\cos^2(\alpha z)dz &=& \frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z}{3\alpha}\sin(2\alpha z)+\frac{1}{8\alpha^2}\cos(2\alpha z)\nonumber\\
\int z\cos(\alpha z)\sin(\alpha z)dz &=& \frac{-z}{4\alpha}\cos(2\alpha z)+\frac{1}{5\alpha^2}\sin(2\alpha z)
\end{eqnarray}
التكاملات integrals باستخدام الدوال الاسية functions :exponential
\index{التركيب}
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^\infty e^{-\beta s^2} ds &=& \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\beta}}\nonumber\\
\int_0^\infty s e^{-\beta s^2} ds &=& \frac{1}{1\beta}\nonumber\\
\int_0^\infty s^2 e^{-\beta s^2} ds &=& \frac{1}{4\beta}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\beta}}\nonumber\\
\int_0^\infty s^2 e^{-\beta s^2} ds &=& \frac{1}{2\beta^2}\nonumber\\
\int_0^\infty s^3 e^{-\beta s^2} ds &=& \frac{3}{8\beta^4}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\beta}}\nonumber\\
\int_0^\infty s^n e^{-as}\, ds&=&n!/a^{n+1}
\label{eqnapp1}
\end{eqnarray}

\addtocounter{page}{1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{الفهرس}

\addtocounter{page}{-1}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: Below is a general solution that I often use for this kind of problems, but it doesn't work here.**

There are three problems problem with my solution in your document:

1. you use `\pagestyle{headings}`, so that is not affected by the `fancyhdr` code.
2. With XeTeX, in right-to-left typesetting `fancyhdr` seems to confuse left and right.
3. The `\fancyheadinit` also seems not to work well with XeTeX.

I have solved this now by redefining the `headings` pagestyle with `fancyhdr`. For use in XeTeX I swap L and R in the `fancyhdr` definitions.

Add the following code before `\usepackage{polyglossia}`:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% redefine pagestyle headings because in xetex, left and right in
% the headers are swapped.
\fancypagestyle{headings}{
  \renewcommand{\headrule}{}
  \fancyhead[RE,LO]{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\thepage}
  \fancyhead[LE]{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\slshape\leftmark}
  \fancyhead[RO]{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\slshape\rightmark}
}
\pagestyle{headings}
```

**Here follows the general solution.**

Here is a small example with `fancyhdr`. The `\fancyheadinit` command changes the font for the headers, in this case a larger, sans serif font. The same can be done for the footer with `\fancyfootinit`, or for both with `\fancyhfinit`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[toc]{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadinit{\large\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Pieter 
Thanks for answering my question in Stackexchange.
I just want to make the font size of chapters and sections that appear in the header smaller than the font size of the manuscript body text. What you have sent does not come with my latex packages and commands.
Is there any further note that can guide me to reduce the font size?
Sincerely
Abed

Comment: Hi Abed, which package doesn't come with your LaTeX? Every decent LaTeX installation should come with the `fancyhdr` package, but if  not, you can download it from CTAN (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). You don't need `blindtext`, it is just used to generate some dummy text, but you can replace that with your own text.

Comment: Dear Pieter, I add what wrote above, but I does not change any thing at my file. The chapter tile in the header still in the same font size. I do want to make the title of chapter in the header 10pt, which is differ from my manuscript body text font size, which is 12pt. I am just trying to fix that, but it does not cone yet.

Comment: You could try `\fancyheadinit{\fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont}`. This makes the headers 10pt. It may not look much smaller, but if you measure the letters you will see the difference. Otherwise try `\fontsize{8}{9}` to see a real difference.

Comment: Dear Pieter, I tried that but I does not work. I think because that page style that I am using is not fancy, headings and plain.

Comment: It seems to have to do with XeTeX and your use of `\pagestyle{headings}`. I have now added a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example featuring font customization.

As a bonus and just in case:
if a bigger font produces a too long text, the package `truncate` will stop it at a given ratio of the total header width (`\headwidth`), and print `...` instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[fit]{truncate}
\usepackage[toc]{blindtext}


\newfontfamily\fancynum[UprightFont={* Light},BoldFont={* Bold}]{AT Hadriano Std}
\newfontfamily\fancytext{Minion Pro Capt}

\fancypagestyle{innersections}{
\fancyhead[RE]{\textbf{\fancynum\small\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\fancytext\small\nouppercase{\truncate{0.8\headwidth}{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textbf{\fancynum\small\thepage}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\fancytext\small\nouppercase{\truncate{0.8\headwidth}{\leftmark}}}}



\begin{document}

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{innersections}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Krebs
Thanks for answering my question.
I just want to make the font size of chapters and sections that appear in the header smaller than the font size of the manuscript body text. What you have sent does not come with my latex packages and commands.
Is there any further note that can guide me to reduce the font size?
Sincerely
Abed

Comment: For this we would need a Minimal Working Example: edit your original post and show us a relevant part of your code, which can be compiled on its own. But I really do not see what prevents you from adding the lines that Pieter or I have submitted. It is unclear what your problem is regarding this code.

Comment: Dear Kerbs, what I need is to make the titles font size in the header lees than that of text. I modified my work example to enable you show what it come.